# Index of vector field $ \mathrm{grad} f (x)$ at critical point of index $\lambda$ is $(-1)^\lambda$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I don't understand why this is true. Near the critical point p, we have $f = -x_1^2 - \cdots -x_\lambda^2 + x_{\lambda +1}^2 \cdots x_n^2$, where $\lambda$ is the index of the critical point, and intuitively, this represents the number of "downwards" directions around it. The index of a vector field is, intuitively, the winding number of a counterclockwise-oriented circle around the point, or more precisely, if $B$ is a ball around $p$ containing no other zeros of the vector field, then the index at point $p$ is the degree of the map from the boundary of $B$ to the sphere such that $q \in B \rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{grad}(f)(q)}{\|\mathrm{grad}(f)(q)\|} $

We have $\mathrm{grad}(f) = (-2x_1,\cdots,-2x_\lambda,2x_{\lambda +1},\cdots,2x_n)$ using the equation for $f$ near $p$. How do I show that the index of $\mathrm{grad}(f)$ is $(-1)^\lambda$?

Answer (score 1):

The map $x\mapsto (-x_1,\cdots,-x_\lambda,x_{\lambda +1},\cdots,x_n)$ is the composition of $\lambda$ reflections in coordinate planes. Therefore, it suffices to show that each such reflection $r$ has degree $-1$. The details vary with the definition of degree you have. For example: using the [volume form $\omega$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Euclidean_coordinates_in_.28n_.2B_1.29-space) on the sphere, I would find the pullback $r^* \omega$ and observe that  $r^* \omega = -\omega$.